# How to combine multiple SQL queries into a single one?

Tags: sql

I have these multiple sql queries that I want to bundle together into one single query, so that I can avoid sending multiple requests to the database from my application ( I want to receive all of these data in one single shot) :

```
1) select pin, officeNum, isVeteran from table18 where pin = 123;

2) select streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress from table1 where case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);

3) select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress from table5 where pin = 123;

4) select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress from table55 where seqNum = 0 and rfa = (select rfa from table18 where pin = 123);

5) select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress from table103 where histCode = 0 and case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);

6) select phone, email from table715 where histSeqNum in (select max(histSeqNum from table715))
      and histCode in (select max(histCode) from table715)
      and case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);
```

Here is my schema :

(Please excuse the bad design, it's from a database created 20 years ago, there is no foreign keys)

-Table18 ( pin(PK), case, officeNum, isVeteran )

-Table1 (case(PK), caseOfficer, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress)

-Table5 (pin(PK), streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress)

-Table55 (rfa(CompositeKey), seqNum(CompositeKey), rfaAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress)

-Table103 (case(CompositeKey), histCode(CompositeKey) )

-Table715 (case(CompositeKey), histSeqNum(CompositeKey), histCode(CompositeKey), phone, email )

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: @juergend. That's for some other question...

Comment: It's a little difficult without seeing a schema, but it looks to me like you're using the subselects to perform joins. If you can give some more information, it should be possible to rewrite without someone having to reverse engineer your schema first.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to merge all these queries into a single one   so that I don't have to send multiple queries to my database (from my application)

Comment: i think showing your table structure, or not using * in these examples would help write one big query. - everything appears to be joinable

Comment: Perhaps start with 1 and 3 (since they share a primary key), then join to 2, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's a set that can be unioned...
(3,4,5)

```
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress 
from table5 where pin = 123
union
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress 
from table55 where seqNum = 0 and rfa = (select rfa from table18 where pin = 123)
union
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress 
from table103 where histCode = 0 and case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);
```

you could put (2) on there also if you don't mind blank states on these...

for example, in 2 write something like:

```
select null unitAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress 
from table1 
where case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);
union
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, null
from table5 where pin = 123
union
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, null 
from table55 where seqNum = 0 and rfa = (select rfa from table18 where pin = 123)
union
select unitAddress, cityAddress, streetAddress, apartmentAddress, null
from table103 where histCode = 0 and case = (select case from table18 where pin = 123);
```

also consider restructuring your nested selects to joins - similar to this: (I bet optimizing these queries will be the performance difference you are looking for)

```
select streetAddress, apartmentAddress, cityAddress, stateAddress 
from table1  t1, table18 t18
where t1.case = t18.case 
and t18.123;
```

then make sure t18 has an index on pin, and t1 has an index on case.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. All queries returns a fixed number of columns. If you still insist on retrieving your columns that way, make sure the columns datatype is the same for all your queries and combine them with unions. I don't recommand that, but it is possible.

Comment: I don't see why it can't be done - there are clearly possible joins between all of the tables.

Comment: @DavidFaber there is now, there wasn't earlier.