# How to combine many queries at one?

Tags: mysql

I have tables

```
# users
 id
 name
# images
 id
 name
# images_data
 id
 users_id
 images_id
```

How i can do request with data like this

```
# users
 id 
 name
 images
```

Where `images` keep list images `name`s (4example after function concat_ws(',',QUERY)).
Input parametr `users.id`.

4example, i have data

```
#users
-1
-admin
--2
--manager
#images
-1
-Blackwhole
--2
--Sun
---3
---Moon
#images_data
-1
-1
-1
--2
--1
--2
---3
---2
---1
```

And i want get

```
#users
-1
-admin
-Blackwhole,Sun
--2
--manager
--Blackwhole
```

Thanks..

Comment: This question is the possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650099/how-to-combine-multiple-sql-queries-into-a-single-one

<br />

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, GROUP_CONCAT(images.name SEPARATOR ',') AS images
FROM users
LEFT JOIN images_data ON users.id = images_data.users_id
LEFT JOIN images ON images_data.images_id = images.id
GROUP BY users.id
```