# Combine Multiple Sql Queries into one

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, count, subquery

I have a column called "status" in a sql table called "latest" which contains five different values new,deployed,resolved,assigned and closed as shown below

```
 Status
--------------
  NEW
  NEW
  DEPLOYED
  NEW
  RESOLVED
  ASSIGNED
  ASSIGNED
  RESOLVED
  ASSIGNED
  NEW
  NEW
  RESOLVED
  CLOSED
  ASSIGNED
```

I want to write a query in which i can count the number of times each of these words occur in the column "status". Currently I'm using count function in 5 different queries like this.

```
 1)select count(status) from latest where status="NEW";
 2)select count(status) from latest where status="DEPLOYED";
 3)select count(status) from latest where status="RESOLVED";
 4)select count(status) from latest where status="ASSIGNED";
 5)select count(status) from latest where status="CLOSED";
```

Is there a way i could combine all these queries into single query without using joins or union to get 5 different count values??

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650099/how-to-combine-multiple-sql-queries-into-a-single-one

Comment: @Aniruddh: Checkout my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**QUERY 1:**

```
SELECT STATUS, COUNT(1) FROM LATEST
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY STATUS;
```

**Your Output would be:**

```
STATUS         COUNT
ASSIGNED       4
CLOSED         1
DEPLOYED       1
NEW            5
RESOLVED       3
```

To get the output in single row with 5 columns you can use:
**QUERY 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='ASSIGNED' THEN 1 END)  ASSIGNED_COUNT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='CLOSED' THEN 1 END)  CLOSED_COUNT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='DEPLOYED' THEN 1 END)  DEPLOYED_COUNT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='NEW' THEN 1 END)  NEW_COUNT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS='RESOLVED' THEN 1 END)  RESOLVED_COUNT
FROM LATEST
```

**Your Output would be:**

```
ASSIGNED_COUNT   | CLOSED_COUNT | DEPLOYED_COUNT | NEW_COUNT | RESOLVED_COUNT
4                |  1           | 1              | 5         | 3
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. **Query 1** can be used where there can be any number of dynamic status. For example, even if there is a status named DEFERRED, it would automatically be included without query change. But, if there is say, no record with status as "NEW", then no data would be returned.
2. **Query 2** can be used to return all the data in a single row. If a new status is to be included, then the query must be modified. If there are no records for a status, then 0 would be returned. **IDEAL FOR DASHBOARD** kind of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.status, COUNT(1) 
FROM latest l
GROUP BY l.status;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT SUM(l.status = 'NEW') AS NEW_STATUS,  
       SUM(l.status = 'DEPLOYED') AS DEPLOYED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'RESOLVED') AS RESOLVED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'ASSIGNED') AS ASSIGNED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'CLOSED') AS CLOSED_STATUS
FROM latest l;
```

**UPDATE**

Use `SELECT...INTO` statement to achieve this, check below query

```
SELECT SUM(l.status = 'NEW') AS NEW_STATUS,  
       SUM(l.status = 'DEPLOYED') AS DEPLOYED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'RESOLVED') AS RESOLVED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'ASSIGNED') AS ASSIGNED_STATUS, 
       SUM(l.status = 'CLOSED') AS CLOSED_STATUS 
       INTO NEW_STATUS, DEPLOYED_STATUS, RESOLVED_STATUS, 
            ASSIGNED_STATUS, CLOSED_STATUS
FROM latest l;
```

Comment: By using the above query will i get 5 different count values??will i be able to store them in 5 different variables??

Answer (score 0):

Try this cool one

```
  Select *
  from
  (
  Select Status,COUNT(*) 'Count'
  from LATEST
  group by Status with rollup
  ) t
  where t.Count is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

1.>

*Select Count(*) as Count,Status from latest where (status='NEW' Or status='DEPLOYED' or status='RESOLVED' or status='ASSIGNED' Or status='CLOSED') group by Status;*

OR

2.>
*select count(status) from latest where (status='NEW' Or status='DEPLOYED' or status='RESOLVED' or status='ASSIGNED' Or status='CLOSED');*